# jQuery animation fade effect

Tags: jquery

The fade effect here isn't working....  `ui.fadebox` is a white div tag that is supposed to fade in and fade out.  It's not fading though, even when the time is set to `5000` it's just like setting the display from block/none.  There's no transitioning...

```
            ui.fadeBox.animate({
                    opacity: 1
                },
                500,
                function () {
                    $('.active', ui.container).removeClass('active');

                    $(ui.banners[idx]).addClass('active');

                    ui.fadeBox.animate({
                        opacity: 1
                    },
                    500,
                    function () {
                        ui.fadeBox.css("display", "none");
                    });
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never set the opacity to 0.  You only ever animate it to 1.

In other words, you are animating from opacity 1->1, and then half a second later animating from 1->1, and then half a second later making it disappear.  So, it stays visible for 1 second, and then it blinks away.

You need to make the second opacity 0, and make it start from 0.

Simplified example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZYmHP/

Another:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZYmHP/1/

Comment: `#test{...}` should probably have `display:none;` set as well, but good example for the sake of this question. +1

Comment: Yes, but that began to complicate the answer, because I wasn't sure if he wanted it `display:none` from the beginning or not.  I have a tendency to over-engineer answers, so I stopped while I was ahead. :)

Answer (score 1):

To make it fade in, set the opacity to `0` before the animation.
(By calling `ui.fadebox.css('opacity', 0)`)

To make it fade out, change the inner `opacity: 1` to `0`.